# Is it possible to use your match from the match box in the replace box with Regex/Replace?

Tags: regex, replace

I have a long list like this

```
sb.AppendLine(product.product_id.Length.ToString())
```

I want to use regex search and replace to change every line to something like this

```
sb.AppendLine("product.product_id " + product.product_id.Length.ToString())
```

Is this possible to do with regex search and replace?

What do I put in the search box and what to I put in the replace box?

**Is it possible to use your match from the match box in the replace box?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, using [capturing parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches).

I assume that product_id is variable.
Search:

```
sb\.AppendLine\(product\.(.+)\.Length\.ToString\(\)\)
```

Replace:

```
sb.AppendLine("product.$1 " + product.$1.Length.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

in vb .net

Dim str As String
str = "sb.AppendLine(product.product_id.Length.ToString())"

Dim RegexObj As Regex
RegexObj = New Regex("^sb.AppendLine((.*).Length.ToString())$")

Dim res As String
res = RegexObj.Replace(str, "sb.AppendLine(""$1"" + product.product_id.Length.ToString())")

in c# .net

string str = null;
str = "sb.AppendLine(product.product_id.Length.ToString())";

Regex RegexObj = default(Regex);
RegexObj = new Regex("^sb\.AppendLine\((.*)\.Length\.ToString\(\)\)$");

string res = null;
res = RegexObj.Replace(str, "sb.AppendLine(\"$1\" + product.product_id.Length.ToString())");

Comment: When you post code, try to format it in code blocks. You can do that by indenting each line 4 or more spaces, wrapping it in ` characters, or just highlighting it and clicking the **{ }** button on the editor.